# Gif on Github pages using a theme

Tags: github, jekyll, gif

I'm trying to get a gif to render on my github pages. The page utilizes a Jekyll theme and is currently rendering my README.md file. For some reason I can get my gifs to render on the readme page: https://github.com/JpBongiovanni/PythonFunctionLibrary/blob/main/README.md

but not my jekyll page: https://jpbongiovanni.github.io/PythonFunctionLibrary/

The code below renders the correct gift for readme, but not Jekyll.

```
![zigzag](/PythonFunctionLibrary/movies/zigzag.gif)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 2 things to edit

The problem is, you haven't setup anything in `_config.yml` file that's why incomplete URL making some troubleshoots. You need 2 things to do!

1. **URL Set-up**
2. **Image Tag Set-up**

### URL Setup

In `_config.yml` just add 2 lines:

```yaml
#_config.yml

url: 'https://jpbongiovanni.github.io/' # your main domain
baseurl: 'PythonFunctionLibrary/' # if you're using custom domain keep this blank example: baseurl: ''

theme: jekyll-theme-hacker
```

Now we are all set with our URL setup, now edit anchor tag or link tag in README.md file.

### Image Tag Set-up

Let's dive into your image tag which is in markdown formate like:

```markdown
![zigzag](./movies/zigzag.gif)
```

edit into this:

```html
<img src="{{site.baseurl | prepend: site.url}}movies/zigzag.gif" alt="zigzag" />

<!-- OR -->

<img src="{{ "movies/zigzag.gif" | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url}}" alt="zigzag" />
```

Here:

- **{{...}}** is a Liquid filter syntax
- **site.url** is collecting **URL** from the `_config.yml` file
- **site.baseurl** is collecting **baseurl** to add that after the url for GitHub Pages
- **| prepend: ** is a filter which means **site.url** will be added before the **site.baseurl**.
  this tag will render this:

```html
<img src="https://jpbongiovanni.github.io/PythonFunctionLibrary/movies/zigzag.gif" alt="zigzag" />
```

That's it. I Guess this will help to do your work perfectly...

**HAPPY JEKYLLING**