# Github pages with Jekyll not showing images in .md post

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I created a simple blog with Jekyll/Github Pages. The directory tree is organized like this:

- _posts

  - post1.md
- assets

  - Untitled.png
  - Untitled1.png
- _config.yml
- index.md

In post1.md I embed images by:

```
![Untitled](/assets/Untitled.png)
![Untitled1](/assets/Untitled1.png)
```

The Github preview works just fine, but in my website it can't show up images. Please help me with this problem, i spent 2 days trying to fix it but still not working. Images in
[Github preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLsGg.png) and [Show on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNS4Z.png)

Answer (score 3):

## 2 things to edit

The problem is, maybe you haven't setup URL in `_config.yml` file that's why incomplete URL making some troubleshoots. You need 2 things to do!

1. **URL Set-up**
2. **Image Tag Set-up**

### URL Setup

In `_config.yml` just add 2 lines:

```yaml
#_config.yml

url: 'https://your-github-username.github.io/' # your main domain
baseurl: 'your-repo-name/' # if you're using custom domain keep this blank example: baseurl: ''
```

Now we are all set with our URL setup, now edit anchor tag or link tag in post1.md file.

### Image Tag Set-up

Let's dive into your image tag which is in markdown formate like:

```markdown
![Untitled](/assets/Untitled.png)
```

edit into this:

```html
<img src="{{site.baseurl | prepend: site.url}}assets/Untitled.png" alt="Untitled" />

<!-- OR -->

<img src="{{ "/assets/Untitled.png" | prepend: site.baseurl | prepend: site.url}}" alt="Untitled" />
```

Here:

- **{{...}}** is a Liquid filter syntax
- **site.url** is collecting **URL** from the `_config.yml` file
- **site.baseurl** is collecting **baseurl** to add that after the url for GitHub Pages
- **| prepend: ** is a filter which means **site.url** will be added before the **site.baseurl**.
  this tag will render this:

```html
<img src="https://your-github-username.github.io/your-repo-name/assets/Untitled.png" alt="Untitled" />
```

That's it. I Guess this will help to do your work perfectly. Fact is this answer was already given by me in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67733921/14387700

...

**HAPPY JEKYLLING**